# char* to std::string

Tags: c++

I have a Character Array (char* pData) in C++, what i want to do is to copy some data (from pData) in std::string. The code looks like this:

```
std::string sSomeData(pData+8);//I want to copy all data starting from index 8 till end
```

The problem is that when above statement executes the string contains nothing in it. 
I guess that my pData is not terminated with '\0' thats why its not working.

Regards,
Jame.

Comment: You ''guess''??! You don't know what data you're working with? In any case, the code should work with a proper null-terminated string (assuming that it has at least 8 characters, which you should definitely check for.)

Answer (score 6):

If you know the size of the `pData`, you can use the construct-from-iterators constructor:

```
std::string sSomeData(pData + 8, pData + size_of_pData);
```

Comment: do note the usage of pData + size_of_pData causes the copy to exceed valid boundary. you need to minus the starting offset to fix this.

Comment: @YeenFei: the `std::string(iterator begin, iterator end)` constructor copies the characters *excluding* the character referenced by the 'end' iterator. Passing a 1-past-the-last-character pointer here is correct.

Comment: @pmjordan, i was interpreting it as size-of-pData (length of the string pointer by pData) instead of sizeof( pData ) ...

Comment: @YennFei: yes, that is exactly how I meant it too. `std::string foo(pData + 8, pData + length);` is correct, as long as length >= 8. It will create a std::string of size `(length - 8)`. From the documentation (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/):

*"...the content is initialized with the values of the elements that go from the element referred by iterator begin to the element right before the one referred by iterator end."*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know whether your data is NULL terminated or not then you should know the size of the data (i.e. how many characters are there). Otherwise there is no way to copy it. When you know the size, you can specify it in the string constructor. Following is a sample code:

```
int main( void )
{
    char p[] = {'N','a','v','e','e','n'};
    std::string s(p+3, p+6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can i use sizeof(pData) operator to calculate size?

Comment: No (not in general anyway). You need to know the size explictly.

Comment: @JStephan: You can use `strlen(pData)` to calculate string length, *if* it is null-terminated.. but then you might as well use the other variant of the solution.

Comment: In this specific case, `sizeof(p)` would return the size, because `p` is an array. In your situation, though, `pData` is a pointer, so `sizeof(pData)` would return the pointer size instead of the size of the referenced buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::string sSomeData(pData+8, pData+8+n)` where n is the number of characters that you want to copy.

Comment: `pData+8+n` will refer to an illegal address. (You meant `pData+n`, but that's already been explained by Victor.)

Comment: @sbi: actually, he said n is the number of characters you want to copy, which here would be (size - 8) ;-)